# iOS Swift WKWebView login with Session

Tags: ios, authentication, uiwebview, wkwebview

I come from UIWebView where I had following code:

```
         let url2 = NSURL(string: URL+"/auth?id="+self.username!+"&pw="+self.password!)                    
            let task2 = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url2!) {(data, response, error) in
                print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
            }

            task2.resume()
```

Doing this I was automatically logged in.
But now with the WKWebView this is not working anymore.

The Code is executed just before loading the request:

```
  self.webView = WKWebView()
  let request = NSURLRequest(URL: portalURL!)
  self.webView!.loadRequest(request)
```

Username and Password are stored on the Device, when the User installs the Application.

How can I get a similar effect with WKWebView?

Answer (score 3):

You'd better add user info to request header. Like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
if needAddHttpHeader {
    urlRequest.addValue("login", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Login")

    urlRequest.addValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Token")
    UBLog(urlRequest)
}
webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

Comment: i want to login with above url (in background) and then load a different Url in the WebView